# Is there a way to highlight only the red faces which has the normals faced the wrong way and then flip them? Without manually pressing every face

Tags: normals

[image]I have a lot of faces, around 500k. Some of the normals is flipped the wrong way, is there a way to highlight only the red faces which is faced the wrong way and then flip them? I have tried to highlight everything and choose recalculate inside/outside but my mesh doesn't seem to grasp it. See picture below.[image]

Comment: If this is a completely connected mesh, then recalculate inside or outside should set them all facing the same direction. So I guess there are other issues with your mesh as well. Some double vertices? Or unconnected geometry? Have you tried selecting all, then hit M > Merge by Distance? Or is it supposed to be unconnected? Then what about hovering your mouse over a blue part, hit L so every connected face gets selected. If all blue parts are selected, hit H to hide them. If now only red faces are left, hit A to select all, then Alt+N > Flip.

Comment: I appreciate your help but unfortunately it did not work :/ this is a pointcloud which was given to me so it is really messy, a lot of holes and vertices everywhere. I think the problem is that it's one mesh, one unity, but the normals is flipped/reversed, I will share another picture for you to see. So the bottom part is red when the top part is blue and contrariwise. So recalculate doesn't work here. Do you have any tips to fix this? (I will add the picture in the original post). *The blue area on the floor is where I have repaired holes.